# Standing waves and Photons

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

There are solutions to Maxwell's Equations called Standing waves, or so I was told [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/349183/are-localized-electromagnetic-waves-possible-solutions-to-maxwells-equations).

If we consider the particle nature of EM waves, what does standing waves mean in terms of photons?

And when electrons excite and then release photons, can these be standing waves? Does that make any sense?

**Edit:** Most surely, this question is not a duplicate of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90646/what-is-the-relation-between-electromagnetic-wave-and-photon). The other question is about the general relationship between EM waves and photons. I want to know about this exact same  relationship, *but for the case of **Standing Waves*** .

Comment: Hi PhyEnthusiast. A standing wave is just the sum of two propagating waves travelling in opposite directions. There is nothing special about standing waves.

Comment: Are standing waves, photons that don't move??

Comment: No. There is no simple relationship between photons and a light wave. The photon is the unit of energy when a light wave exchanges energy with something else. The idea of light being made up of lots of little balls, i.e. the photons, is appealing but utterly wrong.

Comment: Do standing waves exchange energy, then?

Comment: have a look at [Do photons truly exist in a physical sense](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303132/do-photons-truly-exist-in-a-physical-sense-or-are-they-just-a-useful-concept-lik/303165#303165) for more on this. I think this is the closest I've come to an accessible description of what photons are.

Comment: I just want to ask: can the interactions of standing waves be described as photons? Can excited electrons in an atom release a standing wave?