# What does frequency mean in the transition energy of electrons?

Tags: energy, photons, electrons, frequency

I have read many questions on this site about *how do transitions occur ? What happens during transition ?* The answers are extremely good.

What I couldn't understand is **why is frequency related to the energy released during the transition?** What causes this frequency (since I don't think electrons are oscillating while transitioning)?  Or is it defined differently ? Can someone give a pictorial representation of the oscillation of electrons while **transitioning** ?

Also, can this release of photons be explained from the **Bohr's model** ?

If I am wrong somewhere please correct me.

Comment: My two cents. When electron will transit from energy levels $n_2$ to $n_1$ then according to Bohr model it will have an angular momentum change of $L_{2,1} = \frac{(n_2-n_1)h}{2\pi}$. And angular momentum in atom must be conserved, so exactly this same amount of difference in angular momentum is carried away by photon energy/frequency.

Comment: @Agnius Vasiliauskas Thanks for that but I just want to know why the energy released as photon ? And why is frequency associated with that ?

Comment: Well, a simple question, but no simple answer. Short answer is that in a quantum mechanical world energy means a stream of particles, that's it. In classical picture energy is something taken out of the blue, but in QM,- it's very material and **real**, i.e. particles. To help you with second question imagine this. Like you are shaking hand to a friend 10 times in a row, up-and-down. Now try to shake hand these 10 times, but with frequency of 10 Hz,- will you spent a whole bunch more your **energy** in doing that ? Then you understand why frequency related to energy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the electrons do oscillate during the transition.

I don't think you can get this from the Bohr model,  but in simple QM it follows nicely.

Suppose an  electron with charge $q$ starts in a higher state $\Psi_2(\vec r,t)=\psi_2(\vec r)e^{i E_2 t/\hbar}$ with energy $E_2$ and ends in a lower state $\Psi_1(\vec r,t)=\psi_1(\vec r)e^{i E_1 t/\hbar}$ with energy $E_1$

During the transition it is in an intermediate state $\Psi=a \Psi_1 + (1-a) \Psi_2$, and $a$ increases from 0 to 1 in some complicated way that doesn't concern us here.

The electric dipole moment is $\int \Psi^* q \vec r \Psi \, dV$

Inserting the previous expressions this is $ |a|^2 q^2 \int |\psi_1^2(\vec r)| \vec r dV+ |1-a|^2 q^2 \int |\psi_2^2(\vec r)| \vec r \, dV + |a(1-a)| \int (\psi_1^* \psi_2e^{i(E_2-E_1)t/\hbar} + \psi_2^* \psi_1e^{-i(E_2-E_1)t/\hbar}) \vec r \, dV$.

The first two terms have no time dependence (and are probably zero). The third gives $2 |a(1-a)| Re{(\int \psi_1^*(\vec r) \psi_2(\vec r) \vec r dV  )e^{i(E_2-E_1)t/\hbar}})$ so you can see the dipole there is oscillating at just the frequency matching the energy difference.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided a lot of background information, I am going to assume that you are talking about the electron transitions in the Bohr model Hydrogen atom.

An electron can only occupy certain valid shells at specific a distance(radius) from the nucleus. In the ground state, the electron will be in the first shell (K-shell) and will posses lowest potential energy. When exited, the electron jumps to a higher shell and the potential energy of the electron increases.

Now when the electron comes back to the ground state, its potential energy decreases and an equally energetic photon is released. The frequency of the photon is given by the Planck–Einstein relation $E=hv$. There is nothing special relating it to frequency, you can substitute $v$ to find the wavelength too as $E=\frac{hc}{\lambda}$. This can only be explained by quantum mechanics as the classical theory does not allow for an electron to revolve around an atom forever.

Comment: but why is frequency associated with the energy   released ? You didn't answer this.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. It's as if you're asking why acceleration is related to force in $F=ma$. It is what is it as the equation which makes the mathematics and experimental observations agree with each other.

Comment: If you're asking for a derivation of the formula then it is [here](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/48089/course/section/16461/qsp_chapter10-plank.pdf).

Comment: please go once again through the question. I want to ask **why** is frequency associated with the energy released ? Do the electrons oscillate continuously while transitioning ?

Comment: If you are asking what the frequency represents, it is the frequency of the **photon**. The photon in wave form has electric and magnetic fields oscillating at this frequency.

Comment: that's what I want to know. Why is there oscillating electric and magnetic field associated with that transition ?

Comment: That is because accelerating charges produce electromagnetic waves

Comment: accelerating or oscillating  ? I think for oscillating electric and magnetic field we need an oscillating charge.

Comment: No, the correct term is acceleration. A body cannot oscillate without being accelerated. A charged particle in circular motion is not oscillating but will still produce an electromagnetic wave.

Comment: do you know what is oscillation ? What do you mean by this **A charged particle in circular motion is not oscillating** ?

Comment: No offense but maybe you should start with the basics of atomic and wave theory first before moving on to harder topics. Without a solid foundation, you will struggle to understand any of the advanced topics. I am not going to sit and explain to you simple high school physics. You can go to your teacher for that. Oscillation is periodic motion about a fixed mean position. Circular motion has no mean position.

Comment: Google it "whether circular motion is a periodic motion or not ? "

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is quite "simple".
The energy difference between two arbitrary energy levels is associated with a photon that has the same energy as this difference: $E_{photon}=E_{level1}-E_{level2}=\hbar\nu$.
So the frequency is nothing else than the frequency translated inro the energy of the photon. To put it even better: the energy related to the difference in energy levels during a transition can be translated to the photon's energy.

The transition from a collection of superimposed energy states (each energy being higher than the energy of the ground state) is not a wavefunction collapse: the collection of superimposed energy states doesn't contain the ground state itself. The transition **is** a wavefunction collapse if the collection of superimposed energy states falls back (is projected upon), one of the energy states contained in the collection. Anyway, the transition doesn't evolve in a smooth way but in a non-smooth, collapse-like way.